# Twitter Codebird Error

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use codebird to tweet using PHP. Initially I was unable to get Access Token but after I defined CallbackURL in settings that issue seems to be resolved. Now it is returning oauth token:

> Codebird\Codebird Object ( [_oauth_token:protected] => *codehere* [_oauth_token_secret:protected] => *codehere* [_return_format:protected] => 0 [_supported_media_files:protected] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) [_version:protected] => 3.0.0-dev [_use_curl:protected] => 1 [_timeout:protected] => 10000 [_connectionTimeout:protected] => 3000 )

But when i try to tweet i get following error:

> stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [code]
>   => 89 [message] => Invalid or expired token. ) ) [httpstatus] => 401 [rate] => )

Following is my code

```
Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey('copy+paste from twitter', 'copy+paste from twitter'); // I changed it to my   settings

$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();

if (! isset($_SESSION['oauth_token'])) {
// get the request token
$reply = $cb->oauth_requestToken(array(
    'oauth_callback' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
));

// store the token
$cb->setToken($reply->oauth_token, $reply->oauth_token_secret);
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $reply->oauth_token;
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $reply->oauth_token_secret;
$_SESSION['oauth_verify'] = true;

// redirect to auth website
$auth_url = $cb->oauth_authorize();
header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
die();

} elseif (isset($_GET['oauth_verifier']) && isset($_SESSION['oauth_verify'])) {
// verify the token
$cb->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
unset($_SESSION['oauth_verify']);

// get the access token
$reply = $cb->oauth_accessToken(array(
    'oauth_verifier' => $_GET['oauth_verifier']
));

// store the token (which is different from the request token!)
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $reply->oauth_token;
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $reply->oauth_token_secret;

// send to same URL, without oauth GET parameters
header('Location: ' . basename(__FILE__));
die();
}

// assign access token on each page load
$cb->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
print_r($cb);
$params = array(
  'status' => 'Auto Post on Twitter with PHP http://goo.gl/OZHaQD #php #twitter'
);
$reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
print_r($reply);
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Is your callback address the one registered with Twitter in the app definition?

Do you have "read and write" access in the app definition?

Have you exceeded the rate limit for posting?

I'd check those things first, as I don't see anything obviously missing from your code snippet.